# List of chat room members

Tags: iphone, ios, xmppframework

How can I retrieve the list of members of a chat room in using `XMPP framework`?

I tried using:

```
 - (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchMembersList:(NSArray *)items
```

But it returns an empty array

Comment: Did you check your chat room settings for Anonymous joining? If it is enabled you might not get the list of users in the room.

Comment: Are you using this type of chatrooms, XMPP + Jabber? http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-integration--mobile-7190

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is old but I recently encountered this exact issue (`xmppRoom:didFetchMembersList:` is passed an empty array). In my case the problem was that when users got invited to the room they would have a role of "participant" and an affiliation of "none". The `fetchMembersList` method in XMPPRoom looks for items with an affiliation of "member".

You can change the affiliation like so:

```
[xmppRoom editRoomPrivileges:@[[XMPPRoom itemWithAffiliation:@"member" jid:userJID]]];
```

For details on roles and affiliations, see [XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#associations).

Comment: Hi, @onelittlefish I tried you code and it was of big help! But, I tried it in a public room with a user that just joined and it didn't worked, it only worked if the owner of the group tried to give permissions...any Idea how I can bypass this? Here is my [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701372/join-an-existing-xmpp-muc-room-with-owner-privileges-using-ios-openfire-and-robb), hope you could help :)

Answer (score 2):

use this method when you invite users.

```
-[xmppRoom editRoomPrivileges:@[[XMPPRoom itemWithAffiliation:@"member" jid:userJID]]];
```

After you create xmpproom object and call following delegate method

```
-(void)xmppRoomDidJoin:(XMPPRoom *)sender{
    [sender fetchMembersList];
}


- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchMembersList:(NSArray *)items{
    NSLog(@"print user list=====%@",items);
    for (NSXMLElement *xmlItem in items) {
        NSString *jid = [[xmlItem attributeForName:@"jid"]stringValue];
          NSLog(@"print user jid=====%@",jid);
    }
}
```