# Join an existing XMPP MUC Room with Owner Privileges using iOS Openfire and Robbie Hanson library

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework, muc

I am joining an existing MUC room using the next code:

```
XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];
XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"newRoom5@conference.administrator"];

xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:roomStorage
                                                       jid:roomJID
                                             dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoom activate:[self appDelegate].xmppStream];
[xmppRoom addDelegate:self
        delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:[self appDelegate].xmppStream.myJID.user
                        history:nil
                       password:nil];
XMPPMUC * xmppMUC = [[XMPPMUC alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppMUC   activate:[self appDelegate].xmppStream];
[xmppMUC addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

and in after the user joins the room I am trying to change his permissions to owner without using the user that created the room(the actual owners account):

```
- (void)xmppRoomDidJoin:(XMPPRoom *)sender {
//    ADD USERS TO OWNERS LIST
    [xmppRoom editRoomPrivileges:@[[XMPPRoom itemWithAffiliation:@"owner" jid:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[self appDelegate].xmppStream.myJID.user]]]];
}
```

And I get the error, that I don't know for sure if it is related:

```
RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error"
          id="64BBA616-56D7-4CB1-AC07-CBEA4C37E98C" 
          from="newroom5@conference.administrator" 
          to="newuser236@administrator/26ee7a3d">
        <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin">
          <item affiliation="member" jid="newuser236"/>
        </query>
        <error code="403" type="auth">
          <forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
        </error>
      </iq>
```

and the user is not added to the Owners list in Openfire.

Also I want to add that I set:

```
publicRoom : 1 
moderated : 0
membersOnly : 0 
canInvite : 1 
roomPassword : nil 
canRegister : 1 
canDiscoverJID : 1 
logEnabled : 1
```

Any suggestions on how to add the user that just joined the room to the owners list? and also any ideas why I am getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

As I was unable to use the xmpp library I created functionality using PHP, so the issue is not solved but using PHP coding and DB you can go around it.