# not getting Xmpp room chat members list in iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, multiuserchat

i'm trying solution given at [List of chat room members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121475/list-of-chat-room-members) but . But from this link i'm confuse where to put 'editRoomPrivileges' method. i'm facing exact issue of affiliation permission . i tried to set every participants affiliation permission to 'member' from group owner account but i'm getting 'not allowed' error in method

```
- (void) xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didNotEditPrivileges:(XMPPIQ *)iqError
```

I think group owner by defauld have permission to modify affiliations. room is of type of persistent and public .

i have invited user like this ,

```
- (void) xmppRoomDidCreate: (XMPPRoom *)sender
{

//ArrNewRoomInfo contain multiple user to be included in room

for (int  k=0; k < ArrNewRoomInfo.count; k++)  

 {

 NSString *pureNumbers = [[[[ArrNewRoomInfo objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"mobno"] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

  NSString *strInvitedUserName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@elmajabber",pureNumbers];
            [sender editRoomPrivileges:@[[XMPPRoom itemWithAffiliation:@"member" jid:[XMPPJID jidWithString:strInvitedUserName]]]];

 [sender inviteUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:strInvitedUserName] withMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[ArrNewRoomInfo objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"GroupName"]]];

  } 
}
```

please help me to get room member list.

Comment: Hi, Did you found a solution for this?

Comment: hi,yes i got solution for this...i got 'not allowed' error  because of server configuration .  if you are facing same issue please look at your server end setting and make them As follows                                                                                 {access, muc_admin, [{allow, admin}]}.

{modules, [
  {mod_muc, [
             {access_admin, muc_admin},
 ...
 ]}.

Comment: And you can use editRoomPrivileges: after inviteUser: directly